# What were the political goals of the United States' intervention in the Russian Civil War?

Tags: united-states, russian-revolution, combat

My understanding is that the United States sent two separate ground forces to take part in the Russian Civil War

- [Polar Bear Expedition](http:////en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Bear_Expedition)
- [American Expeditionary Force Siberia](http:////en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Expeditionary_Force_Siberia)

Only the Polar Bear Expedition would see combat, fighting the Red Army. The Red Army would of course later emerge victorious.

Although the ideology of the Bolsheviks was undoubtedly different than that of most American politicians, there was not yet a clear track record of the atrocities committed by the Soviet Union. Stalin had not yet conducted his purges for example. I find it unlikely that the US would have intervened solely on the basis of ideology.

What did the United States' hope to achieve by intervening in the Russian Civil War? Were they simply trying to gain favor with the other powers in Europe? Or were they trying to protect American interests in Russia?

Comment: See this thorough review http://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2002/winter/us-army-in-russia-1.html

Comment: And also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_intervention_in_the_Russian_Civil_War

Comment: Questions that are covered by wikipedia or google are out of scope (See [ask]).   I suspect this question will be closed until it is refined to ask for information beyond that which is provided in wikipedia.   The goals of intervention are outlined in the second sentence; having read those, what questions remain?